# Opening text file in python as an array or list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, genfromtxt

I am trying to open a text file in python as an array or a list of list. The file looks like below.
Also, here is a link to the text file.
ftp://rammftp.cira.colostate.edu/demaria/ebtrk/ebtrk_atlc.txt

```
AL0188 ALBERTO   080518 1988 32.0  77.5  20 1015 -99 -99  -99 -99   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *   218.  
AL0188 ALBERTO   080600 1988 32.8  76.2  20 1014 -99 -99  -99 -99   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *   213.  
AL0188 ALBERTO   080712 1988 41.5  69.0  35 1002 -99 -99 1012  60 100100 50 50   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *   118.  
AL0188 ALBERTO   080718 1988 43.0  67.5  35 1002 -99 -99 1008  50 100100 50 50   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *   144.  
AL0188 ALBERTO   080800 1988 45.0  65.5  35 1004 -99 -99 1008  50 -99-99-99-99   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *    22.  
AL0188 ALBERTO   080806 1988 47.0  63.0  35 1006 -99 -99 1008  50 -99-99-99-99   0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0 *    64.
```

I have tried using NumPy genfromtxt but it returned with an error, because it couldn't tell for example that 100100 is two elements in two columns. It treated it as one entry in a column, and so returned error saying the number of columns in each row didn't match.

Is there some way to fix this? Thank you

Comment: Here is a link to the text file. ftp://rammftp.cira.colostate.edu/demaria/ebtrk/ebtrk_atlc.txt

Comment: I agree with numpy genfromtxt ... I couldn't tell either!

Comment: read the file line-by line, using `with open("file") as fd; for line in fd:...` and manually fix the bad `100100`.

Comment: The file, which is the one in the link above, has 10000+ lines.. Do I have to fix each problematic line manually?..

Comment: sortof, if there is a "pattern" to the broken data then you could automate that, i.e. if there supposed to be a fixed number of columns in each row, then it's easy to find all broken rows and trying to adopt.

Comment: Yes there is supposed to be a fixed number of columns in each row! :) it looks very tidy in the link I posted above. So in this case what can I do? Thanks!

Comment: I'll post something shortly, have two sick girls that need my attention right now...

Comment: It seems like each "column" has the name number of characters, so you could use that to split the data. `col1, col2, ... = line[0:x], line[x:y], ...`

Comment: Thank so much! There should be a fixed number of 26 columns for each row.The problem comes because columns 13-16 are not well-separated (i.e. 100100 occurs), and so are columns 17-20 and 21-24.. (I hope they get well soon!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply the delimiter sizes as argument. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

with open('ebtrk_atlc.txt', 'rU') as f:
    data = np.genfromtxt(f,
                         dtype=None,
                         delimiter=[7, 10, 7, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3])
    print data
```

will give as output (omitting the first few lines)

```
('AL0188 ', 'ALBERTO   ', 80712, 1988, 41.5, 69.0, 35, 1002, -99, -99, 1012, 60, 100, 100, 50, 50)
('AL0188 ', 'ALBERTO   ', 80718, 1988, 43.0, 67.5, 35, 1002, -99, -99, 1008, 50, 100, 100, 50, 50)
('AL0188 ', 'ALBERTO   ', 80800, 1988, 45.0, 65.5, 35, 1004, -99, -99, 1008, 50, -99, -99, -99, -99)
```

As you see the `100100` field got separated. Of course you have to supply the correct field types and dimensions, this example just demonstrates that it is possible. For example, changing the code to

```
import numpy as np
import re
import sys

with open('ebtrk_atlc.txt', 'rU') as f:
    dt = "a7,a10,a7,i4,f5,f6,i4,i5,i4,i4,i5,i4,i4,i3,i3,i3"
    data = np.genfromtxt(f,
                         dtype=dt,
                         delimiter=map(int, re.split(",?[a-z]", dt[1:])),
                         autostrip=True)
```

will change the result to

```
('AL0188', 'ALBERTO', '080712', 1988, 41.5, 69.0, 35, 1002, -99, -99, 1012, 60, 100, 100, 50, 50)
('AL0188', 'ALBERTO', '080718', 1988, 43.0, 67.5, 35, 1002, -99, -99, 1008, 50, 100, 100, 50, 50)
('AL0188', 'ALBERTO', '080800', 1988, 45.0, 65.5, 35, 1004, -99, -99, 1008, 50, -99, -99, -99, -99)
```

Stripping away the whitespace around the strings and explicitly setting some types to float. Further documentation can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), check the example at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much! It almost worked. Just one minor problem. When I copied your code and ran it, it said "TypeError: data type not understood".. Btw I am especially interested in keeping the opening zeros, e.g. '080712' of first line.

Comment: Sorry I just did not repeat the whole program, I've fixed my answer so you can copy&paste it. Does it work now? For me it reads your complete file without an error.

Comment: I hate to say this but still it says "TypeError: data type not understood". I have copied yours, and just replaced the spaces in front of the lines dt and data with tab...I wonder where this can go wrong..

Comment: Hmmm. I have just copied it from this posting and for me it works. Not sure what the problem is, bad indentation would be reported as an `IndentationError` in most cases. You should set your editor to show whitespace and other nonprintable tokens maybe you can find something ;-) In ViM that would be `:set list`.

Comment: sounds like a numpy version mismatch

Comment: I have numpy `1.7.1` installed, not sure how old that is :)

Answer (score 0):

Old-fashion parsing is possible since the structure is nicely ordered, a bit length but it seems to do the trick.

Before:

```
$ awk '{print NF}' ebtrk_atlc.txt  | sort | uniq -c
     79 17
     16 18
     92 19
    494 20
    308 21
    405 22
   1769 23
    897 24
   1329 25
   5444 26
     27 27
```

after:

```
$ awk '{print NF}' log  | sort | uniq -c
   8778 27
   2082 28
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

with open("ebtrk_atlc.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        cols=line.strip().split()
        # 26 columns seems to be the target
        # after column 13, split on -
        if len(cols) < 26:
            tmp = []
            for i in cols[-13:]:
                if '-' in i:
                    for n in i.split('-'):
                        if n:
                            tmp.append('-' + n)

                elif len(i) == 6 or len(i) == 9 or len(i) == 12:
                    for n in chunks(i, 3):
                        tmp.append(n)
                elif len(i) == 8:
                    # 50100100 split in 2-3-3-fashion
                    tmp.append(i[0:1])
                    tmp.append(i[2:4])
                    tmp.append(i[5:7])
                elif len(i) == 5:
                    # 50100 split in 2-3-fashion
                    tmp.append(i[0:1])
                    tmp.append(i[2:4])
                elif len(i) == 7:
                    # 0285195 split in 3-3-fashion
                    tmp.append(i[0])
                    tmp.append(i[1:3])
                    tmp.append(i[4:6])
                elif len(i) == 11:
                    # 30120160200 split in 2-3-3-3-fashion
                    tmp.append(i[0:1])
                    tmp.append(i[2:4])
                    tmp.append(i[5:7])
                    tmp.append(i[8:10])
                elif len(i) == 10:
                    # 0180180210 split in 3-3-3-fashion
                    tmp.append(i[0])
                    tmp.append(i[1:3])
                    tmp.append(i[4:6])
                    tmp.append(i[7:9])
                else:
                    tmp.append(i)

                # one final loop to fix strings beginning with a 0
                tmp2 = []
                for i in tmp:
                    if i.startswith('0') and len(i) > 2:
                        tmp2.append(i[0])
                        tmp2.append(i[1:])
                    else:
                        tmp2.append(i)

            # rebuild list
            data = cols[0:-13] + tmp2

            print len(data), data
        else:
            print len(cols), cols
```